# SharePoint 2013 cannot log in after windows update

Tags: windows-server-2012, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

After some updates on Windows Server 2012 Domain Controller, I am unable to login to SharePoint server.

It is asking for credentials 3 times and then it displays blank page. Central admin page is working normally.

In Event I have this:

```
An account was successfully logged on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Type:         3

Impersonation Level:        Impersonation

New Logon:
    Security ID:        domain1\acc.svc
    Account Name:       acc.svc
    Account Domain:     domain
    Logon ID:       0x346FC094
    Logon GUID:     {3d20e910-90e4-2abe-2940-4cfe0b931140}

Process Information:
    Process ID:     0x0
    Process Name:       -

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   
    Source Network Address: -
    Source Port:        -

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      Kerberos
    Authentication Package: Kerberos
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0

This event is generated when a logon session is created. It is generated on the computer that was accessed.

The subject fields indicate the account on the local system which requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or Services.exe.

The logon type field indicates the kind of logon that occurred. The most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).

The New Logon fields indicate the account for whom the new logon was created, i.e. the account that was logged on.

The network fields indicate where a remote logon request originated. Workstation name is not always available and may be left blank in some cases.

The impersonation level field indicates the extent to which a process in the logon session can impersonate.

The authentication information fields provide detailed information about this specific logon request.
    - Logon GUID is a unique identifier that can be used to correlate this event with a KDC event.
    - Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.
    - Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM protocols.
    - Key length indicates the length of the generated session key. This will be 0 if no session key was requested.
```

We have restored Windows server 2012 before the update but the problem is still here. Loop back is disabled.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves the problem:

Hotfix  Windows Server 2012 R2

> KB3177108
>   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53465
>
> KB3167679
>   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53486
>
> KB3175024